# Is there a way to filter material table based on date

Tags: angular, filter, datepicker, angular-material

I'm trying to filter table based on starttime and endtime using mat datepicker. but its not working.
This is my html code-

```
    <mat-form-field><input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp1" (keyup)="dateFilter($event.target.value,'start')" (dateInput)="addEvent($event.target.value, $event)" placeholder="Choose a date"><mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp1" ></mat-datepicker-toggle<mat-datepicker #dp1 ></mat-datepicker>
```

this is my ts file code for manually typing date which is working-

```
dateFilter(filterValue : String,input)  {
debugger;
 this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
 if(input=='start'){
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
    return data.startTime.toLowerCase().includes(filter); };} else{ this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
    return data.endTime.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
};
}  }
```

this function to choose the date from datepicker which is not working -

```
addEvent(filterValue: string, event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
  debugger;
  console.log(event.value);
  if(event.value!=undefined){
    filterValue =this.datepipe.transform(filterValue, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
  } 
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim();
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
  return data.startTime.includes(filter);
};
```

Comment: yes you can! Can you provide some sample data especially for `startTime`

Comment: { name: 'Test script', startTime: '5/1/2019 17:43:09', endTime: '1/5/2019 17:43:19',status:'running'} .. This is my object where i"m doing filter

Comment: So you need to use pipe for `startTime` also as you see it contains time slot also console the value of `filterValue` variable

Comment: Can't I use angular material built-in filter ??

Comment: yes why not wait will show you example

Comment: You can refer my code I already have done but its not able to match the input date with the date already in object

Comment: check the posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `M/d/yyyy` format to parse the date from DatePicker like:

```
this.datepipe.transform(filterValue, 'M/d/yyyy');
```

as per your JSON data, it actually does not contains leading zero's.

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbruis)

I selected `1st May 2019` from the date picker and got the first record in the result.

> EDIT:

You need to register a `filterPredicate` once and then you can set `filter` property of `DataSource`

So just register it in `constructor` or `ngOnInit()` method like:

```
constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe) {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string) => 
        !filter || data.startTime.includes(filter);
}
```

and on click event just:

```
this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim();
```

Comment: Yup now its working .. I didn't know because of this small mistake it was not working .. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Welcome! Feel free to accept the answer, if it helped!

Comment: I just noticed one thing for the first time when you're doing filter its not returning only starttime its returning both .. why is that happening .. just change endtime same as start time in your demo you'll get to know the issue.

Comment: @Priyanka yup just checked Have updated answer and demo also

Comment: Yup its working .. So I just added this inside ngOnInit-
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string) => {
      if(this.type=='start')
      return data.startTime.includes(filter);
      else{
        return data.endTime.includes(filter);
}

Comment: @Priyanka Welcome! and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)